# How to automate Cisco ios switch running-config backup to tftp server using ansible

Tags: ansible, tftp, cisco-ios

I have tried
*ios_command* module to run command
"*copy running-config tftp*"
Next I have to provide ip of tftp server. Followed by destination file name.
I have *tftp* server running and I have ip address of it. But to provide the ip address and file name.
I have tried with sending
ios_command:

commands:

```
-copy running-config tftp
-ip of my tftp server.
```

It didn't worked
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 0):

```
  - name: "Use of Ios commands"
    ios_command:
      commands: 
        - "copy running-config tftp:\n<your_ip_adresse>"
        prompt: '[<your_destination_filename>]?'
        answer: '\r'
```

Comment: The question is off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]